# Можно ли вызывать в Windows API ядра, минуя библиотеки?

Tags: windows, winapi, ассемблер

Можно ли вызывать в Windows API ядра, минуя библиотеки. Вот в Линуксе и FreeBSD это можно сделать из ассемблерного кода с помощью прерывания `int 80h` или инструкции `syscall`. А можно ли что-то подобное делать в виндовсе, никто не встречал?

Comment: в WinXP функции можно было вызывать через int 2Eh, sysenter, syscall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Процесс программирования с помощью `Native API` под `Windows` - не самая приятная штука. Все функции `Native API` *(которые, кстати говоря, официально являются недокументированными и могут меняться от версии к версии)* содержатся в библиотеке `ntdll.dll`.

Вторая проблема при разработке - отсутствие `import library` для этой самой `ntdll.dll`, что решается связкой `LoadLibrary` и `GetProcAddress` для соответствующих функций.

Есть, кстати говоря, и более простой способ - использование [**native-nt-toolkit.**](http://code.google.com/p/native-nt-toolkit/) Пример приложения с помощью этого тулкита можно посмотреть [**здесь.**](http://hex.pp.ua/native-stub.php)

---

**Простого способа вызвать функции `Native API` нет.** Он недокументирован, имеет привязку к версии `ntdll.dll`. Однако при желании разработка с его помощью (или переписывание каких-либо частей кода на `Native` вызовах) вполне как возможна.

Comment: Мрак. Спасибо.

Comment: @mikillskegg, не так уж и мрачно, но много мороки, в основном по причине хреновой (мягко говоря!) документации. @Котик, ссылка сдохла, полагаю, что [вот он](http://code.google.com/p/native-nt-toolkit/).

Comment: @karmadro4 Видимо, не сдохла, а все-таки была кривой изначально :) Спасибо.